# Multiple connections updating same table

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, mysql-connector

I have a code that uses the [MySQL C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api.html) and threads (`pthread`) to create multiple connections to a database (all threads access the same table). Each thread updates **different set of rows** in the same table. In such case, is it necessary to have a `mutex` to ensure no problems in updating the table? What does the standard say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the task of maintaining the data's integrity is more like "on the MySQL side".

Overlaping data access can be handled by table locking requests and rollback logic / transactions but if you're working on different rows, it shouldn't result in data corruption anyway, in case threads concurrently update the table. The database server should handle that properly.